# SPD 2013 text workflow Termination

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a Termination workflow that runs If Nature is changed to termination
I would like a separate workflow to be run after the Termination workflow and check IF "Last day of Contract" Date field is (that Date i.e. 27/02/2018 + 90 days) and IF Yes then send an email. But I would like the workflow to check each Terminated employee "Last day of Contract".

Answer (score 0):

in list settings/information management policy settings

you can create a retention policy to run a sp2010 workflow

you can define your conditions based on a date, then the retention policy timer job (daily timer job) will fire the workflow when the date condition is met

Comment: Thank you for answering me! I followed your steps, but I cannot see where to Add a new policy , Under "List Based Retention Schedule" I see " Source of retention for this list:  Content Types (Change source)"  then under "Content Type Policies" I see Contact, Folder and Workflow Task(SharePoint2013) all three have "Policy" as none and "Retention Policy Defined" as No.

Comment: Also the list has 4 different "Natures" meaning States, i.e. New hire, Consultant, Change, Termination. I only want to affect the Terminations and not any other items with Nature being other then Termination. I basically want to send a reminder email back to Managers after 3 months have elapsed from date of Termination reminding them to copy any emails and OneDrive data before its deleted for ever.

Comment: you have to click on the content type you want to run the policy, probably your content type name is "contact",
once there you'll have to tick the enable retention checkbox and there you are going to select the use 2010 workflow, 
on the workflow you need to place the If condition to only affect the state that you want

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized that I had to create a 2010 workflow and called it "Termination Reminder" this 2010 workflow only has one thing "Send Email" . I am about to put this into place, but before I click OK then OK again to save it all, Can you answer 1 question. Will this Event trigger on all my current existing Termination items that have an entry in "Last Day of Contract" plus 90 days? I must have 500 entries, or will this only start triggering for New Termination events? I dont want to break anything :)

Comment: it will trigger on all the items that have last day of contract populated, so you have to add the condition inside your workflow to avoid it to send emails on other items